# What is better for making a read more, read less button. Pure css or Jquery (support, performance etc.)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just had a long discussion with my friend over what is better to make a read less, read more button.

[My code with Jquery: using,`addClass, Toggle etc`](https://jsfiddle.net/c87pr0no/)

[His code pure Css: using,`pseudo-class :checked`](https://jsfiddle.net/498jjnur/)

websites are ducth btw meer = more, minder = less.

TL:DR whats better for overall use (support, performance etc.) my code or his.

I think my option is better because,
Its ie6+ support correct me if i'm wrong. His ie9+.Ie8 < doesn't support pseudo-class :checked. Also his checkbox doesn't actually contain text (he is using an :after to place text). Wich actually would be better for a application that reads the website for blind people so it doesn't read the button. but I told him that those applications will find a button without text. So he added a label with font-size: 0 so it will find a button with a label show more text, but that text can't change on click without javascript so it's static.

he thinks his is better because,
No use of javascript so it's better for performance. and some more but i forgot :/

What would you use and why?

Comment: If you didn't have to support IE6, I would use pure CSS for this; but since that's not an option, going with CSS and JavaScript is the only solution here. The performance is going to be negligible for something this minor anyways.

Comment: Called checkbox *hack* for a reason... JS is probably the cleaner approach. Opinion based of course.

Comment: For this problem i usually use css3 text-overflow property to hide the content and change it when want to show more.